# trigger ng-click by element id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Ok i have a ng-repeat iterating over a array passing the $index to a ng-click inside the ng repeat like so:

```
<div class="animate-repeat row" ng-repeat="items in sortedTypes">
    <div class="allinfo" id="idwrap-{{items.id}}" ng-click="shohidifelse($index)">
        <div class="allinfo" id="idwrap-{{items.id}}" ng-click="shohidifelse($index)">
            <div class="groupcontent row" ng-hide="showhideinfo[$index]">
                <div class="large-2 columns">
                    <p>{{items.phoneTwo}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row fullprofile" ng-show="showhideinfo[$index]">
                <p>{{items.ContactFirst}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to call a click on this
`<div class="allinfo" id="idwrap-{{items.id}}" ng-click="shohidifelse($index)">`
programatically. i am scroll to this item by the {{items.id}} and i need to call this ng-click from the scroll function. 
Is there a clean way to do this, that I've just missed?

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question!

```
jQuery("#accntselect").on("change", function(e) {
  if (!e.added){
  }else{
    angular.element('#idwrap-'+e.added.id).triggerHandler('click');
    jQuery('#idwrap-'+e.added.id).trigger('click').trigger('click');
    scrollToAnchor('idwrap-'+e.added.id);
  }
});
```

Where e.added.id is the rest of the element's id!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Call the function shohidifelse(), from the jquery scroll function. If you need the $index value to be passed on to shohidifelse(), then pass it on to the jquery function and pass it as a parameter.